# select users where last 5 or more rows in a joined event log table have a specific value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Suppose I have a `user` table with `id` and `username` columns.

And an `event` table with `userid`, `datetime` and `type` columns.

I'd like to select a list of usernames where the latest 5 (or more) entries in the `event` table have `type = 1 or type = 2`.

I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Please Tag your DBMS

Comment: Please show some sample data and desired output

Comment: Do you want to consider users that have less than 5 events in total? For example, a user has only 3 events and all three events have type = 1. Should this user be included in the result?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT USERID,
            [ETYPE], 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY USERID,
                                          (CASE WHEN [ETYPE]=2 
                                                 THEN 1 
                                                 ELSE [ETYPE] 
                                           END) 
                               ORDER BY EDATE DESC) AS RN
    FROM EVENTT
)

SELECT USERID
FROM CTE C
WHERE [ETYPE] IN (1,2)
GROUP BY USERID
HAVING MAX(RN)>=5
```

Comment: I thin that this query have some errors. With RN=1 on where statement HAVING COUNT(RN)>=5 never occurs. Second your PARTITION wont give expected results. The better solution is PARTITION BY (CASE WHEN [TYPE]=1 OR [TYPE]=2 THEN 1 ELSE [TYPE] END)

Comment: OP asked for **latest** 5 entries to have certain type. I think it implies that the query should use the `datetime` column somehow, but your answer doesn't mention it.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov : My bad. Updated the answer.

Comment: @DarkKnight, Now it makes more sense to me, though I'm interpreting the question differently. It is better to wait for some sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

This query should meet your expectations:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id
FROM  User u
WHERE 
  (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM
  ( SELECT TOP 5 * 
    FROM Event e
    ORDER BY EventDate(DESC)
    WHERE e.UserID = u.Id) x
  WHERE u.[Type] = 1 OR u.[Type] = 2
  ) = 5
```

Comment: I agree that the question would be easier to understand if it had some sample data and expected result, but your answer doesn't even use the `event` table. How can it meet the expectations?

Comment: I've corrected query. It was written on the phone and more focused on using the correct formatting than the content of the query. Sorry for fault.

Comment: I see. Still, there is that phrase about **latest** 5 entries in the question. Don't you think that the query should use the `datetime` column somehow?

Comment: I correct this query to get only users witch have <b>latest</b> 5 entries as type = 1 or type = 2. I don't know why i saw in question  sentence "at least" ;)